# How can I select all files with the .ppt extension and make as a list of strings?

Tags: vb.net

My question is how to select all .ppt files in a directory and then make as a string like this:

```
For Each foundFile As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments, Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly, "*.ppt")
    Next

strFileToCopy = (foundFile)
```

But its stoll get an error.
How can i fix this?
Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: What's the error? Also, in your sample you are searching for rtf

Comment: oh sorry i searching for the ppt

Comment: Does `make as a list of strings` mean *store in a `List(Of String)`*  Try to explain enough to overcome language barrier(s)

Comment: I mean i want to encrypt my all .ppt files

Comment: but strFileToEncrypt = (foundFile) not work, becaouse i weant to encryt all the ppt files

Comment: Yeah, you need to spend more time researching and *carefully* explaining what you are playing at.

Comment: Why did you create a for/next loop without doing something. If let say you have declared foundfile before the loop then you would only have the last result of the list but if you didn't then the object "foundfile" doesn't exist anymore when you exit the loop creating an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand the purpose of your code, I suggest to do something like this:

```
Dim listOfPPTs As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
For Each foundFile As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments, Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly, "*.ppt")
    listOfPPTs.Add(foundFile)
Next
```

you would than have a list of .ppt files in

```
listOfPPTs
```

from this list, you can perform actions on each entry in the list, like:

```
For Each aFile As String In listOfPPTs
  encryptFile(aFile)
Next
```

The code for Sub encryptFile I'll leave to you

Regards, Paul